NestJS decorator to undo all changes a method made to the database in case of failures
I want to create a NestJS decorator @Transactional() for service methods that will undo all changes made to the database in case of failures.
import { ConflictException, Inject, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Brand } from './brand.entity';
import { BRANDS_REPOSITORY } from './brands.repository';
import { USERS_REPOSITORY } from '../users/users.repository';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';
import { DATA_SOURCE } from '../database/database.providers';
import { Transactional } from '../../decorators/transactional.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class BrandsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(BRANDS_REPOSITORY) private brandsRepository: Repository<Brand>,
    @Inject(USERS_REPOSITORY) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  @Transactional() // <<==
  async create(user: User, name: string) { // shouldn't make any changes in the database
    let brand = await this.brandsRepository.create({ name });
    brand = await this.brandsRepository.save(brand);

    user.permittedBrands.push(brand);
    await this.usersRepository.save(user);

    throw new Error('Something went wrong');

    return brand;
  }
}


This is exactly why I designed @Aspectjs/persistence. Maybe you can give it a go
import { Transactional } from '@aspectjs/persistence';

export class UsersService {
  em = DATASOURCE.manager;
  findAll(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersRepository.find();
  }

  @Transactional()
  async save(user: User) {
    await this.em.save(user);
    for (const post of user.posts) {
      await this.em.save(post);
    }
  }
}

then in AppModule:
import { getWeaver } from '@aspectjs/core';
import { TypeOrmTransactionalAspect } from '@aspectjs/persistence/typeorm';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory() {
        return {
          type: 'postgres',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 5432,
          username: 'user',
          password: 'password',
          database: 'database',
          entities: [
            /* ... */
          ],
        };
      },
      async dataSourceFactory(options) {
        const ds = new DataSource(options!);
        getWeaver().enable(new TypeOrmTransactionalAspect().configure(ds));
        return ds;
      },
    }),
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}


EDIT: THIS DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY. BECAUSE IF THERE ARE TWO OR MORE REQUESTS AT THE SAME TIME IT MIGHT FAIL. AND THIS DOES NOT SEEM FIXABLE HERE.
This would be the answer to the question.
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export function Transactional() {
  return function (target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    const method = descriptor.value;

    descriptor.value = async function (...args: any[]) {
      const dataSource: DataSource = this.dataSource;

      const queryRunner = dataSource.createQueryRunner();
      await queryRunner.startTransaction();

      const createQueryRunner = dataSource.createQueryRunner;
      const release = queryRunner.release;

      dataSource.createQueryRunner = () => queryRunner;
      queryRunner.release = () => Promise.resolve();

      try {
        const result = await method.apply(this, args);
        await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
        return result;
      } catch (err) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
        throw err;
      } finally {
        dataSource.createQueryRunner = createQueryRunner;
        queryRunner.release = release;
        await queryRunner.release();
      }
    };
  };
}

But I also had to add private dataSource: DataSource parameter to the constructor of BrandsService, because it is used in the decorator.
import { ConflictException, Inject, Injectable, NotFoundException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Brand } from './brand.entity';
import { BRANDS_REPOSITORY } from './brands.repository';
import { USERS_REPOSITORY } from '../users/users.repository';
import { User } from '../users/user.entity';
import { DATA_SOURCE } from '../database/database.providers';
import { Transactional } from '../../decorators/transactional.decorator';

@Injectable()
export class BrandsService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(BRANDS_REPOSITORY) private brandsRepository: Repository<Brand>,
    @Inject(USERS_REPOSITORY) private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
    @Inject(DATA_SOURCE) private dataSource: DataSource, // <<==
  ) {}

  @Transactional()
  async create(user: User, name: string) {
    let brand = await this.brandsRepository.create({ name });
    brand = await this.brandsRepository.save(brand);

    user.permittedBrands.push(brand);
    await this.usersRepository.save(user);

    throw new Error('Something went wrong');

    return brand;
  }
}

